# Can I configure the scale values in the scale selection box?

Tags: qgis, configuration

The scale selection box in QGIS 2.18.16 by default shows standard values as 1 in: 500, 1000, 2500, 5000 .. 1.000.000. This is good for metric scaled maps, but I am often working with old english Ordnance Survey Maps. Is there a way I can add the six inch (1:10.560), one inch (1:63.360), half inch (1:126.720) and quarter inch (1:253.440) ?  It would spare me a lot of digit typing :)

Is there a configuration setting for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add/remove scale value to/from scale list by means of "Setting > Options > Map Tools > Predefined scales" in QGIS 2.18.

[image]

Result:

[image]

It's the same in QGIS 3.